# How to use Responsive Navigation "BreadCrumb", "Navigation Bar", "Navigation Content" in Twincat HMI Engineering to navigate between multiple screens

Tags: twincat, twincat-hmi

I have multiple setting screens and I want to navigate between them. For example, I have a Setting screen, under which there are multiple selection options like General Settings, Parameter Settings, Backup Settings. And if I am inside General setting page, then the headline should be like **Setting > General Setting**. And from General Setting page I should be able to go back to setting page by clicking on the ***Setting*** > General Setting option. Images are attached for reference.

For this I want to use any useful option out of Breadcrumb, Navigation Bar, Navigation Content. It would great if I could get some sample or example for this.

Thanks in Advance

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOFQL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCdvO.png)

I am checking with the properties settings of these tools but not able to get the desired results. Please guide.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The NavigationBreadCrumb control works together with navigation bar control. Since it looks like you dont want the navigation ribbon in your project you just want a breadcrumb.
My suggestion would be to configure your navigation in a navigation bar control, set the target region control to.
But make width of navigation bar control 0 so it does not appear.
Now use a breadcrumb control on screen.
Whenever you navigate to your required contents, on the target region the bred crumb will show the path.
There are no samples of these controls I could find, but you can create a new project with Project Generator and see how these controls are configured to work together.
[Web Navigation Project generator template](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/te2000_tc3_hmi_engineering/1150907060312482971787.html&id=1765672988063938705)

Comment: Hi Mr. Siddhant, thanks for your valuable input. I am trying with 'visibility = collapsed' option for navigation bar and only displaying the breadcrumb.